# How to scale up or down by a percent value consistently?

Tags: percentages

I'm scaling an value and it works as I intend when the scale is 1 or greater but it doesn't seem to scale as intended when scaling down.

```
// increase by 10%
amount = 10
scale = 1
total = scale + amount/100

// decrease by 10%
amount = 10
scale = 1
total = scale - amount/100
```

I know this is easy but I'm blanking on this.

Work as intended meaning, I'm zooming in on an image and zoom in is a nice gradient but scaling down the image disappears in 9 steps. I would like it to scale gradually at a consistent rate.

Edit. I found this in my other class. I think it does what I want but is there be another way to write it?

```
scaleByAmount = amount/100

if (currentScale<=1) {
    newScale = currentScale+currentScale*scaleByAmount;
}
else {
    newScale = currentScale+scaleByAmount;
}
```

Comment: `doesn't seem to scale as intended` Define "*as intended*".

Comment: It seems to me like the "total" is the correct factor ... Increase by 10 per cent is equivalent to multiplying by $1.1$ and decrease by 10 per cent is equivalent to multiplying by $0.9$.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem here is.

Comment: I'm scaling an image in and out. It seems that zoom out happens rather quickly while zoom in increases the image size at a relatively normal value when the scale is less than 1

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Again, what do you expect? Note that increasing by 10% then decreasing by 10% will not return you to the original value, but rather to $\,0.9 \cdot 1.1 = 0.99\,$ of it.

Comment: @dxiv That might be the issue then. As I scale up 10% of 1 would be .1 while 10% of 100 would increase by 10. So I need to increase and decrease by a consistent value no matter the current scale?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts That depends on what you want to achieve, and how you document/convey that to your users. In the context of zooming, it's common to consider all percentages relative to the *original* size.

Comment: I thought it was typical to zoom in or out by the same constant factor in both directions--when you want the "scale" to get larger, you multiply, and when you want it to get smaller, you divide. For example, multiplying by $1.1$ nine times and then dividing by $1.1$ nine times will get you back to the same scale you started with.

Comment: @DavidK Do you mean something like `size*.1` to zoom in and `size/.1` to zoom out?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts It should be $size \cdot 1.1$ to zoom in, and $size \cdot \frac{1}{1.1}$ to zoom out. Remember that $size \cdot 1$ is just the original size, so $size \cdot 0.1 = size \cdot (1-0.9)$, which is a $90$ percent decrease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $size⋅1.1$ to zoom in, and $size⋅\frac{1}{1.1}$ to zoom out. Since $size⋅1$ is just the original size, so $size⋅0.1=size⋅(1−0.9)$, which is a $90$ percent decrease.

In general, if you want to increase by $x \%$, then the formula is $size \cdot (1+x \%)$. If you want to decrease by $x%$, then the formula is just $size \cdot (1-x \%)$.